# How to create a custom JSON based on form values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a JSON based on a dynamic form values below, when the user submits, i am displaying the json feed in #results

Is it also possible to get all the values in the form when generating the JSON, I want to get the

- name, ids,
- title information,
- input value etc

  and then create/display the JSON in the order below?

A working version can viewed here :

http://jsfiddle.net/dev1212/GP2Y6/25/

Currently its not retuning any values and getting some undefined..
the code peice i tried is below

```
<script>

    x = function(selector){

        var attrs = [];

        $(selector + " input").each(function(){

            var attrObject = {};

            $(this.attributes).each(function(index, attr){

                attrObject[attr.name] = attr.value;
 attrObject[attr.va] = attr.value;
                //console.log(attrObject)
            });

            attrs.push(attrObject);
            attrObject = {};

        });

        return attrs;
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

        alert(JSON.stringify(x("#myform")));

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/www/include/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    x = function(selector){

        var attrs = [];

        $(selector + " input").each(function(){

            var attrObject = {};

            $(this.attributes).each(function(index, attr){

                attrObject[attr.name] = attr.value;
                //console.log(attrObject)
            });

            attrs.push(attrObject);
            attrObject = {};

        });

        return attrs;
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

        alert(JSON.stringify(x("#myForm")));

    });

</script>

<form id="myform" class="form-wd">

    <input class="ui-dform-text" type="text" title="data for network.node1.eth0.ipaddr" name="network.node1.eth0.ipaddr">

</form>
```

Comment: is this an addition to the existing function or replacement to the JSON function?

Comment: @user244394 the `x` function is a replacement for your `serializeObject` function. Try pasting it into a .html page and opening that page in your browser.

Comment: Thats working but its not picking up the values in the inpt box andi am gettign some extra stuff like  "undefined": "ui-dform-text and "ui-dform-text": "ui-dform-text"  how do I disable those[{
    "undefined": "ui-dform-text",
    "type": "text",
    "text": "text",
    "title": " data for network.node1.eth0.ipaddr",
    " data for network.node1.eth0.ipaddr": " data for network.node1.eth0.ipaddr",
    "name": "network.node1.eth0.ipaddr",
    "network.node1.eth0.ipaddr": "network.node1.eth0.ipaddr",
    "class": "ui-dform-text",
    "ui-dform-text": "ui-dform-text"
}

Comment: @user244394, that's strange... what browser are you using?

Comment: the existing serialization code i have currently captures all the values. I will post the output for you.. doesnt output ina custom JSOn structure..that i want

Comment: any idea why it not gettign the input values? It seem to get everything else. I am using jquery.dfrom to read from a JSON to generate the form..

Comment: @user244394 Here is a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/tBdL2/2/, I have FF 14 at work and FF 16 at home and both of them work for me... what version of jquery are you using? I don't think it matters but just in case I run across something.

Comment: I posted my code here http://jsfiddle.net/dev1212/GP2Y6/25/ and its using your code . you will notice its not getting the input value for example 198.198.198.0 in the input text value(s) are not getting returned